# My question asks something for game purposes, there is an answer with practical orientation

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

[What are some mortal dangers in temperate woods?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/3083/537)

I asked this in order to accumulate ideas for a game I am running with some friends. There is a community answer, providing that exactly.

However now the question has been answered in a sensible and practical way. What I mean is - an answer, that IMO is far more valuable for people, going out in the woods. and so - in the spirit of this site.

Should I change the accepted answer?

Answer (score 4):

Ultimately you are the OP, it is your choice.  Personally, I like the idea of accepting the practical answer.